# How to overload "@" operator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

How can we overload the `@` operator?

I know that we can overload the `+`, `*`, etc. operators by implementing the `__add__`, `__mul__`, etc. methods, but what is the equivalent for `@`?

Answer (score 5):

The `@` operator was introduced in python 3.5 to facilitate matrix multiplication (see [PEP 465 - A dedicated infix operator for matrix multiplication](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html?highlight=matmul#pep-465-a-dedicated-infix-operator-for-matrix-multiplication)).

As indicated in the PEP definition, the `@` operator can be overloaded using `__matmul__` as it was initially introduced to perform **mat**rix **mul**tiplication.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def __matmul___(self, B):
        # some operations on self.A and B
        return ...
```

Like any other operator, you can overload its in place version `@=` using `__imatmul__` as well as its reflected version with `__rmatmul__`.